# Angular, Find, and Push

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one array called *products* and another called *sells*:

```
sells = [];
products = [
  {id:1, name:'something', price:30},
  {id:2, name:'something', price:30},
  {id:2, name:'something', price:30},
  {id:3, name:'something', price:30}
]
```

Given a product id, I want to take an entry from *products* and append it to *sells*. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `map` you can not initialize `sells = [];`, becouse `map` always return array. But as you initialized `sells = [];`, you can ofcourse use `forEach`:

```
products.forEach(function(product) {
    if (product.id === 5)
         sells.push(product);
});
```

A lot of cool functions for find, where, map and other things you can find in [lodash](http://devdocs.io/lodash/) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there can be multiple entries with the same id, you can use the `map` function to return an array consisting of all entries with a particular id like this:

Assume, we want to find all entries related to `id == 2`,

```
var id_arr = products.map(function(entry) {
                 if(entry.id == 2) {
                     return entry  
                 }
             })
```

Now, id_arr contains all entries with `id == 2`. Now use `concat` to add to the `sells` array:

```
sells = sells.concat(id_arr)
```